# Hibernate session.update/session.delete does not work

Tags: java, hibernate, session

code:

```
public void test() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    User u = new User();
    u.setUsername("user1");
    session.delete(u);
    session.close();
}
```

I want to know why deletion does not work

Comment: more code need to be added

Comment: tx = session.beginTransaction(); tx.commit(); are missing maybe?

Answer (score 1):

try before `session.close()`

```
session.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to delete non-managed entity that is not attached to session. In order to manipulate entity you should first attach it to session:

```
User u = (User) session.get(User.class, 1L); 
session.delete(u);
```

Above is this sample of loading by id, so if you are restricted to username you have to write a more complex query.